# unable to change color of mdtopappbar

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I can't change the color of MDTopAppBar in any way, it should be black but it remains orange like the theme in the python code: self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
can someone help me?
kivy code:

```
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "screen-1"
            md_bg_color: [24/255, 24/255, 28/255, 1]
            text: 'chadsdsadt'
            icon: "coffee"

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"              
    
                MDTopAppBar:
                    elevation: 1
                    pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    md_bg_color: [0,0,0,1]

                    MDRoundFlatButton:
                        text: 'Account'
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                        size_hint: 1.5, 0.7
                        md_bg_color: "white"

                    Widget:
                        size_hint: 0.2, None

                    MDRoundFlatButton:
                        text: 'List'
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                        size_hint: 1.5, 0.7
                        md_bg_color: "white"

                    Widget:
                        size_hint: 1.9, None
```

I expected it to calmly change color to black